# Will payments with intent Authorize be displayed in end users billing statement

Tags: paypal

I am using paypals restful api.  When creating a new [payment object](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#create-a-payment) if I set the intent to `authorize` and the `payment_method` is a credit card will they be able to see the pending authorization on their credit card billing statement?  Or do I actually have to collect the payment before it is viewable on their statements?

We are trying to implement a verification system where we make 2 trial authorizations on the card that they can confirm then we cancel the authorization.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the buyer should be able to see the authorization on his credit card statement . Previously I did some testing for the transaction type as authorization with my own card and I was able to see the authorization on my card statement .